# What book is Wayne reading?

Tags: story-identification, cosmere, mistborn, wax-wayne-novels

What book is the following based off of? I believe that Sanderson based it off a real book since the last book Wayne reads (or at least described) is a fairly obvious reference to *Watership Down*.

> Wayne put his feet up on the table in their hotel suite, a new book open in front of him. He'd picked it up earlier, when poking through the city.
>
> "You oughtta read this thing, Mara," he called to Marasi, who paced back and forth behind his couch. "Strangest thing you ever heard. **These blokes, they build this ship, right? Only it's meant to go up. Uses a big explosion or some such to send it to the stars. These other blokes steal it, right, and there's seven of them, all convicts. They go lookin' for plunder, but end up on this star what has no--"**
> <sub>*Bands of Mourning - Chapter 18*</sub>

<sup>(emphasis mine denoting story description)</sup>

So what book, if any, is Wayne reading?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it is a book, but the plot is very similar to the British show *[Blakes 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blake%27s_7)*

It has Roj Blake as a freedom fighter, accompanied by 6 other petty criminals. Blake was arrested and falsely convicted by a totalitarian Federation regime, and when being sent to the penal colony he and other convicts take over the ship.

It ran for 4 years in the mid 70's. While it isn't a book, some license may have been taken.

Comment: There was a novelisation of Blake's 7, written by Terry Nation.

Comment: Also, the other details don't match and there weren't actually 7 petty criminals, but 6: Blake, Avon, Vila, Jenna, Gan and Cally. Zen, the shipboard computer, made 7